# Socket communication with ActiveX EXE

Tags: vb6, activex

I am developing socket reading on an ActiveX EXE (i.e on  a seperate thread).

How many sockets i can safely read independently?

I am working on windows XP OS.

Comment: Independently of what? And safely with respect to what?

Comment: @Piskvor, Independently of one another (offcourse an ActiveX EXE runs in seperate process) and safely from thread safety point of view.

Comment: Thread safety isn't an issue as far as I have ever seen, unless you mean something else by that than what I'm thinking.  "Sockets I can read" sounds odd though, are you asking about Winsock control instances that are actively connected and passing data?  If so, probably close to as many as you could use in your main program.

Comment: @Bob Riemersma , Thank you for the reply.Yes, i mean how many winsock objects can be run independently with each object operating on its own thread? I am looking into this.Please provide if you have any additional information regarding this.

Comment: just as a comment: i don't know the limits but i'm sure that the limits on XP are significantly higher than 80 both for number of threads and number of sockets. the issue will be how you structure everything not the underlying OS limits...

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an operating system limit - I think I remember running up against a limit of 80 sockets on the XP machine I was using several years ago.

Comment: Have you succesfully run 80 sockets on 80 threads independently?

Comment: @ramu: No, they were just 80 instances of winsock objects opened in response to 80 clients.  The program was event driven as usual.  How would threads make a difference?

Comment: i am writing code for doing communication on each socket independently.That is why i opted for ActiveX EXE.Client application just triggers the communication and ActiveX EXE will notify client for events.So my concern here is on two aspects.  1.) Maximum no.of sockets an application can create (From OS perspective)  2.Maximum no.of threads for which VB can provide thread safety.Hope it is clear now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you abandon your effort and go with a commercial solution. I remember going down this path back in the 90s and running into a brick wall with ActiveX EXEs as far as threading goes.  The thing is that ActiveX EXEs are apartment threaded, not free-threaded, so you don't get completely independent threads.

And doing server side threads properly is hard enough in modern languages, let alone ones that weren't designed for this purpose.

I ended up purchasing [Server Sockets](http://www.dart.com/ptsrv.aspx) from Dart.  Easily the best investment for that project.  The performance is truly great - you are only limited by the system resources.

Comment: I am checking with trial version of the component that you suggested.Thank you for sharing info.

Answer (score 0):

MSWINSCK.OCX is a very old way of doing things; it came with Visual Basic 6.0 and i remember using it way back when.  i'm not sure the licensing on it... apparently it registers fine under 32-bit win7, but not 64-bit; here's a link to how to get it to register on 64-bit systems: http://angrybyte.com/windows-hacks/mswinsck-ocx-for-64-bit-windows-7-vista/

if you have an MSDN subscription or similar that gives you the ability to download the developer tools (bizSpark, etc. will do it too) then i believe that will also give you a license to redistribute the .ocx.

(btw, i don't actually remember the interface, but i seem to remember it being at least slightly more intuitive than the berkeley socket() interfaces.)

however, personal recommendation given your requirements: learn the APIs, there are lots of examples out there, and just write yourself a class that encapsulates them in a similar way as, say, the .NET Socket class... the APIs aren't that hard and i'm sure there's lots of help to be had here as well, and that's probably better than relying on something that's out-of-date like the control...